# Azure notifications hub how can I use installation Id in a tag expression?

Tags: azure-notificationhub

I've been setting up a project to use Azure Notifications Hub to provide push notifications using the installation modal described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management.

The basic setup and creation of an installation with a couple of iOS test devices works without any issue and sending notifications to all devices at the same time using the online test send capability or the .NET SDK works as expected.

An issue is occurring when trying to use a tag expression to target a notification to a specific device. As described in the documentation:

> The installation model makes it easy to do individual pushes - targeting specific device. A system tag "$InstallationId:[installationId]" is automatically added with each installation based registration. So you can call a send to this tag to target a specific device without having to do any additional coding.

Sounds great but when setting the tag expression to `$InstallationId:[installationId]` both the online test send and the .NET SDK return 400 Bad Request.

Screen shot from Azure portal test send:
[image: Screen shot from Azure portal test send]

Can anyone provide any more information on using an installation like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation id is required to be wrapped in curly rather than square braces as the documentation suggests. For example:

`$InstallationId:{installtion_id}`